# Python Selenium Open driver as mobile phone

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I want the following output when I open a browser with selenium in Python

[image]

I have tried the following

```
options = options.Options()

mobile_emulation = {
        "deviceMetrics": { "width": 400, "height": 822, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Mobile Safari/537.36"
    }
mobile2 = {"deviceName", "iPhone 12 Pro"}
options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile2)

browser=webdriver.Chrome(desirable_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())
```

I have tried both with `mobile2` and with `mobile_emulation` but I can't make it work, it opens with smaller size but still a full PC browser instead of what I want.

How do I programatically get to the output in the screenshot?

Comment: do you want to resize the browser? you cannot get actual behavior of a mobile device to reproduce issues, only screen size you can get

Comment: @DickensAS I want it to be shown as above. The browser fully opened and the actual webpage on the middle as is in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

currently we don't know the parameters for `chrome_options.add_experimental_option("windowTypes", ["webview"])`

for now the window can be maximized, but the mobile view will apear at the **left side** without any control bars, not in center

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time 

mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "Pixel 5" }
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("windowTypes", ["webview"])
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

time.sleep(10)
```

Here `Pixel 5` is a pre defined size in your google chrome

[image]